# DI Error in Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm fairly new to Angular 2 and Typescript. I have a DI Error as below that I couldn't solve. I was trying to understand how this DI works:

I'm trying to build a simple signup component that uses a service for validation and REST API operations.

Here is my component:

**authentication.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { User } from './user';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'authentication',
    styles: ['input[type=email].ng-invalid {border: 1px solid #dd0000}'],
    template: `
    <h3>Sign Up</h3>
    <hr>

    <form (ngSubmit)="signup()" >
        <input type="email" name="email" required
        [(ngModel)]="user.email"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" required
        [(ngModel)]="user.password"/>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <span class.has-error>{{hasError}}</span>`
})
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationComponent {

    public error: Error;
    public user: User;

    constructor(public userService: UserService) {}
    public signup(): void {
        this.userService.init(this.user);
        this.userService.signup().subscribe(
            s=>console.log(s),
            e=>console.log(e)
        )
    }

    get diagnostic () {
        return JSON.stringify(this.user)
    };
}
```

And this is my component:

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { User } from './user';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

public user: User;

constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private headers: Headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
    private requestOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers: headers})) {}

    public init(user: User) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    signup (): Observable<Response> {
        if (this.user.password !== this.user.passwordConfirm) {
      return Observable.throw(new Error('Şifreleriniz uyuşmuyor!'))
        } else {
          return this.http.post('/signup', this.user, this.requestOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the stack:

```
Error: DI Error
    at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:958:33)
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1239:20)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1365:20)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1405:20)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2937:23)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2976:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2908:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2777:25)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8491:56)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11935:49)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.injectorGet (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12315:53)
    at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:11790:31)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2973:28)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2908:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:2777:25)
```

Comment: You don't need `@Injectable()` for components, as `@Component` is already a subtype of it, see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injectable

Comment: @begben :) I was just trying. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to use singleton service pattern  (means having different instances scoped to component(s) only), you have to put `providers:[UserService]` in **`@Component`** decorator as shown below,

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'authentication',

    providers: [UserService]    ///<<<===here

    styles: ['input[type=email].ng-invalid {border: 1px solid #dd0000}'],
    ...
    ...

})
```

But let's say if you want to have a single instance of your **`UserService`** then you have to define it in **`@NgModule`** decorator of your **`root or app component`**

```
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@NgModule({
   imports:[...]

   providers:[UserService]      ///<<<===here
   ...
   ...
})
```

Comment: Is this the general way of using singleton services in Angular 2? I mean if I want to use singleton should I add providers of module and one more thing... Is it have to be the root or top module or can I create module scoped services?

Comment: For Module scoped service i m not sure. But you can try that. But for application scoped, top module or root module and for component scoped, inject it to component level.